# Changing xlim automatically changes ylim for geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think my problem is best explained by an example:

```
set.seed(12)
n <- 100
x <- rt(n, 1, 0)

library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x))
p
p + xlim(min(x), 300)
```

[default xlim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeOzp.png)

[new xlim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xw3r.png)

Why does the y axis automatically change when I change xlim? The density should not change, so it does not make sense to me. When I use base plot this does not happen.

```
plot(density(x))
plot(density(x), xlim = c(min(x), 300))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `xlim` completely drops observations that are outside of the range. Try using `p + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(x), 300))`.

Comment: Thanks, the thing with coord_cartesian works. However there are no x-values larger than 300. To make it more clear: The problem also occurs for p + xlim(min(x), max(x) + 300)

Comment: I am not sure what it's doing exactly but using `xlim` seems to "extend" the density to the end of the interval specified, therefore pushing the maximum down. If you play around with the limits e.g. `xlim(min(x), 200)`, `xlim(min(x), 100)` etc, you will see that the peak approaches 0.3 as you approach the actual max(x). It almost as if `xlim()` adds observations for every value of x in the range. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Use `geom_density(..., n=2^16)` or similar for a more stable experience.

It would appear that in contrast to `density`, the function `geom_density` does take the x range set via `xlim` into account when deciding at which points to evaluate the density estimation. However, the *number* of such points remains fixed at 512 (unless using `n` to set it to a higher value). Hence the larger the x range, the more likely some peaks will be missed. I think this should be documented.